Quickest way to compute the sum of squared elements of the result of a matrix multiplication?
I want to do something like this in Python
sum(square(matmul(A, B)))

There are various ways you can achieve this behavior, e.g.,
sum(np.square(np.matmul(A, B)))

or
np.lingalg.norm(np.matmul(A, B)) ** 2

I haven't profiled it yet, but I suspect the second option will be faster (less ops, fused operations, etc.).
Are there other approaches that could potentially beat this? I'd like to profile various approaches to solving this. I'm not restricted to numpy.

Whats the dimension of your matrices?

Why sum and not np.sum? The former is significantly more expensive on Numpy arrays.

@Onyambu There's large variance in the sizes but probably O(10^3) - O(10^4) on the number of rows in A. I'm not totally sure of the number of columns

@JérômeRichard ah I just used it as a quick example, but I also wasn't aware np.sum was faster on numpy arrays

If the matrix is relatively square, or at least the number of column is significant like >300, then most of the time should be spent in the matrix multiplication anyway so the rest does not matter much. Large matrix multiplications are already well optimized on most platforms (especially relatively square ones by default) so there is not much to do. Note that single precision matrix-multiplication can benefit from accelerator like GPUs. Such details matters a lot.

@JérômeRichard We don't use GPUs in this case, but why is your comment alluding to single precision only? There's CUDA backends for all precisions and also mixed precisions.
I'm checking on the sizes right now.

Double-precision GPU matrix multiplication acceleration is only available on some (expensive) server-side GPUs, not PC ones nor even all server-side ones (the two later are designed to be fast only on single precision since they mainly target Games/AI/image-related applications). Besides, double-precision takes twice more time to move data to/from the GPU. Not to mention it takes more space on the VRAM so it may not fit in it. Thus, most of the time it does not fit people needs or does not worth it enough. This is why I only mentioned this for single-precision.

So put it shortly: having an API for that does not means it will be fast. It can be slower on GPUs than on CPUs (and this is generally the case on my machine with a Nvidia 1660S GPU).
